# Filter data from one sheet and paste into another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter data from one column of sheet1 and put complete data set to sheet2 with headers.  It would be best if paste as values.
Tried code, but its not working as expected.

```
Option Explicit
Function FilterAndCopy(rng As Range, Choice As String)

    Dim FiltRng As Range
     'Clear Contents to show just new search data
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents
     'Set the column to filter (In This Case 1 or A)
     'Change as required
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=Choice
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FiltRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy Data across to sheet 2
    FiltRng.Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    'Display Data
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Set FiltRng = Nothing
End Function

Sub formshow()
'Show Search Form
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Is it possible to use value of a fixed cell of sheet2 to give criteria to filter ?

Comment: Why are you using a function? What is calling the function? A function should return values, not manipulate worksheet cells.

Comment: ^^ You need a sub to perform this. Also,  looks like you might be after a worksheet _change event in sheet2 tied to a particular cell. That cell contains the filter value. When changed it will invoke the event. However, you would need to find a way to pass the filter range either by prompting for it or coding it into the sub.

Comment: @QHarr .. I am bit new to VBA and didn't get your solution. Can you please help with the code.

Comment: Welcome. So you are trying to write a function and as @teylyn rightly points out, a function returns something to the cell it is called from i.e. it doesn't carry out copy paste operations. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel).  When you want to perform actions a series of actions such as copy paste you write a [sub](http://analystcave.com/vba-function-vs-vba-sub-procedures/).

Comment: When you want to fire a macro in response to something you use an event. In this case, you want to take a value from a worksheet cell so I proposed the event to be a [worksheet_change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel). You set the target to be the cell you want to respond to. Say, cell A1 has the filter value then that is the target cell and if that changes the event should fire

Comment: However, in your function you are attempting to pass a range as a parameter i.e. the range you want filtered. So this too needs to be present in the sub somehow. You cannot pass it as an argument to the worksheet change event. So can it be hard coded as a range? i.e. you specify the filter range? Failing that, if the range must be an argument that is passed you can then present an [inputbox](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2458/inputbox.htm) to the user prompting them to select their filter range. Or use a sub that is tied to something like a button push which would also prompt for range

Comment: With your `rng.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=Choice
` does that mean `rng` and `Choice` are defined in another procedure?  Could you incorporate the definitions into what should be a `Sub`?